# How can I force devices to get IPv4 addresses from my AT&T router?

Tags: router, dhcp

This is driving me nuts and I'd appreciate some help.

**THE SETUP**

- A small Ethernet LAN with an AT&T gateway + router.
- The LAN has two PCs and 20 Raspberry Pi devices.
- All dynamic IPs (DHCP)

**THE PROBLEM**

The system I'm building needs the Raspberry Pi devices to have IPv4 addresses. Right now some of the Pi devices get IPv4, but some are getting only IPv6 addresses. **How can I force the router and/or the devices to make sure the devices each get an IPv4 address?**

**THINGS I'VE CHECKED AND TRIED**

- According to the router, there is a pool of about 200 IPv4 addresses available, so there is plenty of address space for the 25 or so devices that are on this network.
- [Mistakenly thinking "IPv6 and IPv4 are mutually exclusive", part 1] I tried to use [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23884/force-ipv4-address) to force one of the Pi's to use IPv4. I only succeeded in getting it to *not* pick up an IPv6 address, so now it doesn't show up on the network at all. :-(
- [Mistakenly thinking "IPv6 and IPv4 are mutually exclusive", part 2] I tried disabling IPv6 inside the ATT router and reset the network. Devices which formerly had IPv6 addresses stopped showing up altogether. I re-enabled IPv6 and the devices came back... except for that one device noted above :-(

I've been fighting with these devices like crazy, rebooting them and whatnot, and they only pick up IPv6. Some of the Pi's pick up IPv4 like I want, the others are IPv6 only. All the Pi's are running the same code.

What can I do?

Comment: Missing IPv4 has nothing to do with the presence of IPv6. Are you thinking that the two types are mutually exclusive?

Comment: So are you sure DHCP is properly set up on the Pis in question? Because it very much looks like it isn't.

Comment: @user1686 I'm very new to all this. As you can see from my question (and more importantly from the link I put in there) I *was* thinking that but now I'm learning that's not the case.

Comment: @DanielB that's a good thought, but there are 20 Pi's and they all contain the same code. If the problem was related to DHCP, wouldn't that problem afflict them all in the same way...?

Comment: I reworked the question to no longer imply that "getting an IPv6" address is part of the problem at all.

Comment: What DHCP client are you running inside the Raspberry Pis? How are you checking that all of them run the same code – are you perhaps cloning one SD card to all of them?